# jQuery exclude child element from click event

Tags: jquery, events

I'm trying to exclude click event on `<div>` tag:

Here is my html:

```
<div class="event" style="height:150px;width:150px;border:1px solid #dddddd;padding:10px">
  <div class="number">10</div>
  <div class="wrap"><a style="display:block;color:#FF0000">Event Name</a></div>
</div>
```

here is javascript:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.event', function(e) {
      if($(e.target).not('.wrap')){
          console.log('Hello');
      }
  });
```

But for some reason it does not work for me. I don't want click event to fire when clicking on `.wrap` or `<a>` element.

Here is jsbin as well: https://jsbin.com/ziyukuyefo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you can use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: .not() won't work in your condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code
- `not()` returns a jQuery object so your condition will always be truthy
- Since you have a anchor element in `wrap` `e.target` may refer to that not the `wrap` element itself

You can check using closest() to see whether there is an element matching the selector in the ancestor tree

```js
$(document).on('click', '.event', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.wrap').length) {
    snippet.log('clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.wrap a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event" style="height:150px;width:150px;border:1px solid #dddddd;padding:10px">
  <div class="number">10</div>
  <div class="wrap"><a style="display:block;color:#FF0000">Event Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another option is to stop the event propagation, which may not be appropriate in all the scenarios