# Exclude button from div function on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I have a div defined in which there is a button. When the div is clicked, a function is called. I would like to exclude the button from the function, that is, when the button is clicked the function will not be called, but when any other content of the div is clicked the function will be executed.

Something like this:

```
<div onclick="function('ID_other_DIV');">
    Click here<br /> 
    X<br /> 
    X<br /> 
    X<br /> 
    <button id="toggle_instalation" @click="doSomething">Do something</button><br />
    X<br /> 
    X<br /> 
</div>
```

I tried to do this some using javascript by adding something like this to the function:

```
var x = document.getElementById(element);
    if (x.id === 'toggle_installation') {
        return;
    }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because my function has a div passed as the element and not a button.

Thank for help.

Comment: you can use <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587858/jquery-exclude-child-element-from-click-event>

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do it many ways. I think the better one would be doing it
   checking if

```
e.target.tagName
```

matches your button tag. Check
TechySharnav's answer.

2. Using e.stopPropagation() to stop the child element to interfere
   it's parents tag's function.

```
<div id="div">
            Click here<br /> 
            X<br /> 
            X<br /> 
            X<br /> 
            <button id="toggle_instalation">Do something</button><br />
            X<br /> 
            X<br /> 
        </div>
    
    <script>
        const div = document.getElementById('div');
        const toggle_instalation = document.getElementById('toggle_instalation');
    
        const doSomething = (e)=>{
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
        }
    
        div.addEventListener('click', doSomething)
    
        toggle_instalation.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
         e.stopPropagation()
    
        }) </script>
```

3. By removing the event listener on clicking the button.

```
    toggle_instalation.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{ 
    div.removeEventListener('click', doSomething)
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need `event.stopPropagation()` on the in the function trigered by the button click to prevent it bubbling up to the parent.**

What this allows is a click handler on the button that does not register onto the parentdiv - so clicking the button only triggers `functionTwo()`. Also as noted by @TechySharnav - you need to pass the event object into the functionsin order to stopthe progation.

Note that I am using inline function calles here - to match yours, but I would suggest you do it via `addEventListeners('click', xyz)`

```js
function functionOne(event) {
  console.log("function one was called")
}

function functionTwo(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("function two was called")
}
```

```html
<div onclick="functionOne(event)">
    Click here<br /> 
    X<br /> 
    X<br /> 
    X<br /> 
    <button id="toggle_instalation" onclick="functionTwo(event)">Do something</button><br />
    X<br /> 
    X<br /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `event` object to the function, and check if `button` element is clicked using `tagName` property.

```js
function A(e, id) {
  if (e.target.tagName != "BUTTON") {
    console.log(id); /*Your code goes here*/
  }

}
```

```html
<div onclick="A(event, 'ID_other_DIV');">
  Click here<br /> X
  <br /> X
  <br /> X
  <br />
  <button id="toggle_instalation" @click="doSomething">Do something</button><br /> X
  <br /> X
  <br />
</div>
```